# Assembly: loop through a sequence of characters and swap them

Tags: c++, loops, assembly, reverse, masm

My assignment is to Implement a function in assembly that would do the following:
loop through a sequence of characters and swap them such that the end result is the original string in reverse ( 100 points )
Hint: collect the string from user as a C-string then pass it to the assembly function along with the number of characters entered by the user. To find out the number of characters use strlen() function.

i have written both c++ and assembly programs and it works fine for extent: for example if i input 12345 the out put is correctly shown as 54321 , but if go more than 5 characters : the out put starts to be incorrect: for example if i input 123456 the output is :653241. i will greatly appreciate anyone who can point where my mistake is:

```
.code

_reverse PROC 
  push ebp     
  mov ebp,esp  ;stack pointer to ebp

  mov ebx,[ebp+8]       ; address of first array element
  mov ecx,[ebp+12]  ; the number of elemets in array
  mov eax,ebx   
  mov ebp,0         ;move 0 to base pointer 
  mov edx,0     ; set data register to 0
  mov edi,0

Setup:

  mov esi , ecx
  shr ecx,1
  add ecx,edx
  dec esi

reverse:

  cmp ebp , ecx
  je allDone

  mov edx, eax
  add eax , edi
  add edx , esi

Swap:
  mov bl, [edx]
  mov bh, [eax]

  mov [edx],bh
  mov [eax],bl

  inc edi
  dec esi

  cmp edi, esi
  je allDone

  inc ebp
  jmp reverse

allDone:
  pop ebp               ; pop ebp out of stack
  ret                   ; retunr the value of eax
 _reverse ENDP

END
```

and here is my c++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
extern"C"
char reverse(char*, int);

int main()
{
  char str[64] = {NULL};
  int lenght;

  cout << " Please Enter the text you want to reverse:";
  cin >> str;
  lenght = strlen(str);

  reverse(str, lenght);

  cout << " the reversed of the input is: " << str << endl;

  }
```

Comment: Haven't noticed any actual errors yet, just really weird stuff.  If you're going to use EBP as a general-purpose register, you should leave out the `mov ebp,esp` stuff.  (And just access your args with an offset from ESP).  Comments like `set data register to 0` are useless.  What would be useful would be a description of what your function uses EDX for.  `mov eax,ebx` at the top of the function appears useless, why not just load into EAX in the first place?  Your only use of EBX in the rest of the function is to put bytes in BL and BH.

Comment: One bug is that you should be saving/restoring EBX like you do EBP, because it's call-preserved in all the common 32-bit calling conventions.  You probably have another bug somewhere, since stepping on your caller's EBX value probably wouldn't cause the behaviour you see.  You should single-step through your code in a debugger to see what it does.

Comment: Thank you So much Mr. Cordes for your great and constructive comments i am sorry i uploaded such a poor a code with no comment at all , i was frustrated with my code so much, i forgot to look at my stupid comments.

Comment: first part of the code is what our instructor has gave us to work with so i wasnt even looking at what was going on in there , i replaced EBX with EAX as you told me and it worked fine. fixed the comments. saved and restore EBX. and since its my second term in college i have never been told anything about single step debugging. i did it and figured where my mistake was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't comment your code, so IDK what exactly you're trying to do, but it looks like you are manually doing the array indexing with MOV / ADD instead of using an addressing mode like `[eax + edi]`.

However, it looks like you're modifying your original value and then using it in a way that would make sense if it was unmodified.

```
  mov edx, eax         ; EAX holds a pointer to the start of array, read every iter
  add eax , edi        ; modify the start of the array!!!
  add edx , esi

Swap:
  inc edi
  dec esi
```

EAX grows by EDI every step, and EDI increases linearly.  So EAX increases geometrically (integral(x * dx) = x^2).

Single-stepping this in a debugger should have found this easily.

---

BTW, the normal way to do this is to walk one pointer up, one pointer down, and fall out of the loop when they cross.  Then you don't need a separate counter, just `cmp / ja`.  (Don't check for JNE or JE, because they can cross each other without ever being equal.)

Comment: i have used addressing mode as you told me and fixed the increment of  EAX geometrically. Also used pointers for comparing instead of index and since i didn't know they can cross each other without even being equal i used JA commend as you suggested and it worked perfectly

Comment: @ArashDe: glad it helped.  You should click the checkbox under the vote arrows to mark this answer as accepted, if you feel like it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Overall you the right idea to start at both ends of the string and swap elements until you get to the middle. Implementation is horrible though.

```
mov ebp,0         ;move 0 to base pointer
```

This seems to be loop counter (comment is useless or even worse); I guess idea was to swap `length/2` elements which is perfectly fine. HINT I'd just compare pointers/indexes and exit once they collide.

```
mov edx,0     ; set data register to 0
...
add ecx,edx
mov edx, eax
```

Useless and misleading.

```
mov edi,0
mov esi , ecx
dec esi
```

Looks like indexes to start/end of the string. OK. HINT I'd go with pointers to start/end of the string; but indexes work too

```
cmp ebp , ecx
je allDone
```

Exit if did length/2 iterations. OK.

```
mov edx, eax
add eax , edi
add edx , esi
```

`eax` and `edx` point to current symbols to be swapped. Almost OK but **this clobbers eax**! Each loop iteration after second will use wrong pointers! This is what caused your problem in the first place. This wouldn't have happened if you used pointers instead indexes, or if you'd used offset addressing `[eax+edi]`/`[eax+esi]`

```
...
```

Swap part is OK

```
cmp edi, esi
je allDone
```

Second exit condition, this time comparing for index collision! Generally one exit condition should be enough; several exit conditions usually either superfluous or hint at some flaw in the algorithm. Also equality comparison is not enough - indexes can go from `edi<esi` to `edi>esi` during single iteration.